# Disabling ActionSheet dismiss on ipad when user touches outside popover

Tags: ios, ipad, uiactionsheet, popover

I have an actionsheet showing in my app and it all work fine on the iphone. However, on ipad it automatically creates the actionsheet within a popover and I can't get it to disable the dimissing whe the user touches outside the actionsheet.

I have changed how the actionsheet is displayed for the ipad and is now shown using:

```
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Choose a preloaded picture", @"Use a photo", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    actionSheet.tag = 1;
    [actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 0, 300, 300) inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [actionSheet release];
```

I have also tried using.

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
     return NO;
}
```

Any idea on how I can stop the uiactionsheet popover from dismissing when a user touches outside the actionsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:` method won't be called because it's a UIPopoverControllerDelegate method, and you're dealing with a UIActionSheet.  Since the UIKit automatically creates the popover controller for you, you won't get a chance to set its delegate.  You could access the popover view itself with `[popoverActionsheet superview]`, but that won't give you the UIPopoverController.

From a user experience standpoint, Apple would ask you not to implement such behavior— if you need to present options in a modal fashion (where they don't go away until the user makes a choice) then the user will be more familiar with a UIAlertView, or [a modally-presented view controller of your own](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).